# How to remove app_dev.php / app.php from the symfony using virtual host on amazon ec2 by ssh?

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2, vhosts

I was ran into the problem and after many hours spending on this issue. I come up with this simple solution. Which works for me. This is very simple for those who don't know about the virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

To set virtual host in the amazon ec2 instance.

Your Document root on ec2 : `/var/www/html`

Assuming that you are at `you-server-ip/` folder

**First Step** : `cd etc/httpd/conf.d`

**Second Step** : `touch vhosts.conf`

**Third Step** : `sudo nano vhosts.conf`

Now this is the Main Step:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName here-your-ip/domain-name
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/folder-name/web 
<Directory /var/www/html/folder-name/web>
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

**Folder-Name: Write folder-name when your symfony files in the folder. if they are on root then remove folder name from the above code.

If you want more information: You can read this article also.

[https://nouveauframework.org/blog/vhosts-running-multiple-sites-on-a-single-aws-ec2-instance/](https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-aws-setting-up-a-virtual-server/)